# Which screen size in Pygame for an 3.5 inch LCD?

Tags: python, pi-2, lcd, pygame

i try to fill out my whole LCD screen in Pygame with the best sharp resolution possible. So there is a difference between computer screen and the LCD.

My LCD has resolution is 480×320. So choosing this resolution numbers would be the best solution?

Comment: Without knowing anything except what you've posted here about the screen, what other answer do you think you could get?  I'm wondering if I'm missing the actual question.

Comment: this statement makes no sense `So there is a difference between computer screen and the LCD` .... why are you asking us which resolution you would find acceptable ... it is up to you to decide

Comment: You misunderstand, with that statement I mean, that a code that produce a screen that covers half size of a computer does not automatically produce a half size of a Raspberry Pi screen.